# Notepad++ plugin CCompletion how get it to work?

Tags: notepad++

recently I installed CCompletion plugin for notepad++ v6.3.2. I opened in npp one .cpp(class implementation) and .h(class definition) file. Then I started to type and pressing ctrl+spacebar. Nothing happened. No auto complete. When I go to plugins > CCompletion > CCompletion I can see mine class, functions, macros and etc. Please can you help me with this issue.

1. I tried to change shortcut (ctrl+spacebar) in Shortcut Mapper.
2. CCompletion is working when I type standard defined functions and types, e.g. "const", "string", "printf" and etc.

Thank you very much,
Emil

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link can help you.

http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/bef197e7/

on the second paragraph.

then you can see how to use it whithin notepad++ plugins>>>CCompletation>>help